# PYQT5 - How to keep layout when QToolBar is floating

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtoolbar

I'm having problems with my `QToolbar`.

I got a QToolBar and used a QVBoxLayout inside it to dispose my QPushButtons.

My problem was when I floated my ToolBar around the QVBoxLayout used to make lose its layout. After I put it back inside de dock the layout was back to normal.

**I'd like to know if there is any way to fix the same layout for any  situation.**

*I tried to implement two different layouts for each status, fixed and floating, but also didn't work.*

**The only way I found was forget the QToolBar and re-implementing my own personalized QWidget and simulate my own ToolBar so it did work well.**

Comment: Did you add a `QVBoxLayout` using `QToolBar::addWidget` method? (You shouldn't add such widgets to a tool bar)

Comment: Can you provide an example so that people can give it a try?

Comment: That's basically what I've been doing:

self.setFixedSize(102, 865)

        self.mywidget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()


        self.vbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.vbox.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 0, 0)

        <add my buttons inside my vbox>

        self.mywidget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.addWidget(self.mywidget)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4zGDZvY.png

Comment: @Y.Melo Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], in the question itself not a screenshot.  If you make it easier for people to help you, the more likely they are to bother.

Comment: I just edited my question to be more specific. I also found the solution. The best solution was implement my own ToolBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QToolBar` takes care of its own layout, you shouldn't be worry about it. You should add actions or widgets and it automatically lays out the items horizontally or vertically regarding the orientation.

[QToolBar Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#details):

> Toolbar buttons are added by adding actions, using `addAction()` or `insertAction()`. Groups of buttons can be separated using `addSeparator()` or `insertSeparator()`. If a toolbar button is not appropriate, a widget can be inserted instead using `addWidget()` or `insertWidget()`. Examples of suitable widgets are `QSpinBox`, `QDoubleSpinBox`, and `QComboBox`.

For example, the following code snippet yields the following layouts:

```
ui->mainToolBar->addWidget(new QPushButton("A"));
ui->mainToolBar->addWidget(new QPushButton("B"));
ui->mainToolBar->addWidget(new QPushButton("C"));
```

- Horizontal:

  [image]
- Vertical:

  [image]
- Float:

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the layout of the `QToolBar`. It manages its own layout, by doing so you have somewhat broken it.

`QToolBar` is a high level widget which handles its content with `QActions`. You need to create actions in your application, and add these actions using `addAction()` or `insertAction()`.

Styling the `QToolBar` should be done either by subclassing your current `QStyle`(difficult) or using stylesheets(easy)

Comment: So what u recommend me is to not use buttons inside a layout in my toolbar, is that it? I'd rather use "addActions" into my toolbar then play with it? I'm just starting with Qt. So, using Actions instead of QPushButtons in a QVBoxLayout inside my toolbar would still let me make changes like, "remove margins", "remove spacing", "set icons", and all these design changes?